# Taylor's formula and its quadratic term

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, triangles, quadratics

I struggle with the following problem:

For a function
$$f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}~,$$
$f$ attains its maximum for $z_0= e^{i\pi/3}$, $f(z_0)=F_{max}.$

Assume we may use Taylor's theorem (identifying $\mathbb{C} =\mathbb{R}^2$) and write
$$ f(z)= F_{max} + \underbrace{f^\prime(z_0)(z-z_0)}_{=0} + \frac{1}{2}f^{\prime \prime}(z_0)(z-z_0,z-z_0) + O(|z-z_0|^3).$$

Now I hope to get an error term of the form
$$ F_{max} - f(z) = c(|z-z_0|^2) + O(|z-z_0|^3)~,~ c=const.~~~~~~~~~(1)$$

That would be true if the quadratic form $f^{\prime \prime}(z_0)$ would be just a multiple of the identity, which would in turn imply that $f$ takes the same values on small circles around $z_0$ (right?).

What I know is that $f(z)=f(\tilde{z})$ whenever the triangles $(0,1,z)$ and $(0,1,\tilde{z})$ are similar, for example $f(i)=f(1/2+i1/2)= f(1+i).$
But those values don't happen to lie on a circle around $z_0$, I think.

Can I use this information show that $f^{\prime \prime}(z_0)$ is just a multiple of the identity?

Or is there maybe another way to obtain equation $(1)$?

Thank you for helping.

Comment: When you write the triangle $(0,1,z)$, do you mean the triangle with vertices $0$, $1$ and $z$? If so, then the triangle $(0,1, \frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2})$ isn't similar to the other two..

Comment: Yes I do refer to the vertices. And I think they all are similar since they all have the same angles $\pi /2, \pi /4 , \pi / 4.$

Comment: ah, your right...I drew a picture. It wasn't to scale ;)

Comment: Well, given two fixed points, there are at most 12 triangles similar to any given one with those fixed points. To see that, just notice that fixing two points determines an edge of the triangle. Pick one of the edges of the triangle to be the given edge. There are 4 similar triangles which share the same labelled edge. You can two this for 2-more edges of the triangle...which gives 3*4=12 total possibilities.

Comment: So you only know a-priori that given a complex number $z$, your function $f$ takes the same value at 12 other points (possibly nondisctinct).

Comment: That seems right. The point $z_0 = e^{i\pi /3}$ in this understanding describes an equilateral triangle. I think it's true that  for $\varepsilon > 0$ it also holds $f(z_0+\varepsilon) = f(z_0- \varepsilon)$ (again the triangles are similar). (In general it should hold that $f(z_0+ [a+ib])=f(z_0+[-a+ib]).$) That gives two points on a circle around $z_0$ with the same $f$-value,  would a third point help me in order to understand the quadratic form $f^{\prime \prime}(z_0)$?

Comment: Anyway, I don't see why more out of those at most 12 points (describing similar triangles) should lie on a circle around $z_0$.